# How can I use OpenLayers3 to put an icon on a selected point of interest in my map?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3, javascript-framework, arcgis-js-api

I am absolutly new in **OpenLayers 3** and I have create the following page that use it and that show an **Open Street** map in which when the user click on a point it retrieve the GPS coordinates of this point:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>    <!-- Map Container -->


    <!-- JavaScript to create a simple map, With this JavaScript code, a map object is created with a MapQuest Open Aerial layer 
         zoomed on the African East coast: -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rome = ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.5, 41.9]);


        var map = new ol.Map({                // Creates an OpenLayers Map object
            target: 'map',                      // Attach the map object to the <div> having id='map0

              // The layers: [ ... ] array is used to define the list of layers available in the map. The first and only layer right now is a tiled layer:
              layers: [       
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],

            // The view allow to specify the center, resolution, and rotation of the map:
            view: new ol.View({
                // The simplest way to define a view is to define a center point and a zoom level. Note that zoom level 0 is zoomed out:
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.5, 41.9]),
                zoom: 10
            })
        });


        map.on('click', function(evt) {
            var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
            alert("COORDINATE: " + prettyCoord);
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see in my code, it is pretty simple I have use this function to retrieve the GPS coordinates:

```
    map.on('click', function(evt) {
        var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
        alert("COORDINATE: " + prettyCoord);
    });
```

My problem now is: how can I put something like a pointer icon on the selected point in the map? I want put an icon like the one shown in this tutorial: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/icon-negative.html

but that have to be shown in the selected point.

I want to do something like give to the user the possibility to select a point of interest on my map but I can't find a solution. How can I do it?

**EDIT 1**: this is the JSFiddle on my example: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/uqcyudex/1/

Comment: That depends.  If you want the point to be at the exact center of a point in the map you would require a way to get the coordinate of that point first, though a WMS server, for example.  If you just want to put a marker where the user clicked, that should be easy.  If you could create a JSFiddle out of your example I'd be willing in showing you how it could be done.

Comment: @AlexandreDubé At the end of my original post I have added a JSFiddle of the example on which I am working on.
So as you can see in the JSFiddle, clicking on a point of the map, an alert message showing the coordinates of the clicked point is retrieved, it show something like: "COORDINATE: 41° 54′ 46″ N 12° 20′ 30″ E" that I think represent the GPS coordinates of the clicked point. What I need is simply add something like a "vector icon" on the clicked point to hightlight it.

Comment: Here, I have asked a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731134/display-markers-popups-whit-openlayer3/34769351#34769351, you have a working jsfiddle example as an anwer to the question

Comment: Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/copser/0zpm9mws/5/, I'm displaying markers on openstreetmap using openlayes3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector layer to add to you map to which you configure with a vector source.  Upon clicking on the map, you can clear the source first, then add a feature to the source, which gets rendered in the map.

See your updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqcyudex/5/

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

...

// add it to the map
layers: [       
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
vectorLayer
],

...

// clear the source and add the feature
vectorSource.clear();
var feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(evt.coordinate));
vectorSource.addFeatures([feature]);
```

To have the vector feature styled as a marker, look at this example to see how it's done: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/icon.html